# R: automate table for results of several multivariable logistic regressions

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15), age = c(25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39), sex = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0), bmi = c(35, 32, 29, 26, 23, 20, 17, 35, 32, 29, 
26, 23, 20, 17, 21), Phenotype1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), `Phenotype 2` = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Phenotype 3` = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Phenotype 4` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 15 x 8
   Number   age   sex   bmi Phenotype1 `Phenotype 2` `Phenotype 3` `Phenotype 4`
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1      1    25     0    35          0             0             1             0
 2      2    26     1    32          0             1             0             0
 3      3    27     0    29          0             0             1             0
 4      4    28     1    26          0             1             0             0
 5      5    29     0    23          0             0             1             1
 6      6    30     1    20          0             1             1             1
 7      7    31     0    17          0             0             1             0
 8      8    32     1    35          0             1             1             1
 9      9    33     0    32          0             0             1             0
10     10    34     1    29          0             1             1             1
11     11    35     0    26          0             0             1             1
12     12    36     1    23          0             1             0             1
13     13    37     0    20          1             1             0             1
14     14    38     1    17          1             1             0             1
15     15    39     0    21          1             1             0             1
```

Hi all,
I have a dataset of 100 patients (15 are shown here), 3 covariates and 50 phenotypes(4 are shown here).
I want to perform a multivariable logistic regression for each phenotype using age, sex and BMI as covariates,
I would like to get a table like this, where I have the p-value, OR and confidence interval(CI)per each of the covariates.
[image]

I just don't know how to start.
Thank you very much for your help!

Best,
Caro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function that should accomplish what you need. There are likely more elegant and more R-like ways of doing this, but this approach worked in my testing:

```
## Load libraries
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


## Define a function to create your summary table
summary_table <- function(x) {
  
  # Capture number of columns passed to the function
  num_vars <- ncol(x)
  
  # Pre-define lists that will be populated and then collapsed by rest of function
  models <- vector("list", length = num_vars)
  first_tables <- vector("list", length = num_vars)
  second_tables <- vector("list", length = num_vars)
  
  # Loop to create each row for the final table
  for (i in 1:num_vars) {
      
    models[[i]] <- glm(x[[i]] ~ age + sex + bmi, family = "binomial", data = df)
      
    first_tables[[i]] <- broom::tidy(models[[i]])
    first_tables[[i]]$OR <- exp(first_tables[[i]]$estimate)
    first_tables[[i]]$CI1 <- exp(first_tables[[i]]$estimate - (1.96 * first_tables[[i]]$std.error))
    first_tables[[i]]$CI2 <- exp(first_tables[[i]]$estimate + (1.96 * first_tables[[i]]$std.error))
      
    first_tables[[i]] <- as.data.frame(first_tables[[i]][first_tables[[i]]$term != "(Intercept)", c("term", "p.value", "OR", "CI1", "CI2")])[1:3,]
      
      
    second_tables[[i]] <- first_tables[[i]] %>% 
                            pivot_wider(names_from = term, values_from = c("p.value", "OR", "CI1", "CI2")) %>%
                            select("p.value_age", "OR_age", "CI1_age", "CI2_age", "p.value_bmi", "OR_bmi", "CI1_bmi", "CI2_bmi",
                                   "p.value_sex", "OR_sex", "CI1_sex", "CI2_sex")
    
  } 
  
  # Combine the rows together into a final table
  final_table <- do.call("rbind", second_tables)
  final_table <- round(final_table, 3)
  row.names(final_table) <- rep(paste0("Phenotype", 1:num_vars))
  
  return(final_table)

}

## Let "df" be your data.frame with 100 rows and 54 columns

## Use the summary_table() function, passing in the 50 columns containing your Phenotype outcome vars (I assumed they're in columns 5:54)
final_table <- summary_table(df[5:54])

## Write the final table to your working directory as a CSV
write.csv(final_table, "final_table.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alec. That answers my question completely.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I try to use the algorithm on 1000 instead of my initial 100 patients I get the error: "Execuition halted". Is there a way to use this code on 1000 patients, too?

Comment: Hmm in theory it should work for a dataset of any size. Does the error say anything in addition to "Execution halted"?

Comment: Hi Alec, thanks for your answer. My first dataset is 100 patients and 54 phenotypes and the second is 2000 phenotypes and 500000patients, so maybe the second one is just to much for the system (I am running it on a HPC). Unfortunately, the error is only "execution halted -  I looked the error up online and saw that sometimes for very large datasets this error occurs, but I was not able to find a solution yet. But thanks a lot for your help!